# How to authenticate user using Spring Ldap Authentication with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I am using Spring mvc 5 and Spring Ldap with xml base configuration. I have read many tutorials for this and all are using Spring boot with embedded servers, but i need to authenticate users with actual ldap server in spring mvc 5 with spring security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using an LDAP ContextSource that has a URL pointing to your LDAP Server. For [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-contextsource):

```
<ldap-server
    url="ldap://ldap.example.com:53389/dc=springframework,dc=org" />
```

I'd strongly suggest that you start with a working example that points to and embedded LDAP instance before pointing to your production LDAP server. A few things that you will need to adjust for are deciding if you are performing [bind authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-bind) or [password comparison](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-ldap-pwd) based authentication. You will also need to ensure that you adjust your settings to align with the LDAP schema of your LDAP server you are pointing to.